# Get selected value of <select> loaded by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, select, get

I have a  html tag and with ajax and jquery i fill it with more

```
<option></option>
```

My problem is:

When i try to get with

```
jquery $("#select").val();
```

it return always "undefined".

I also try with .text(); and its the same.

This is my jquery/javascript code to fill the option select drop down list:

```
function CaricaDaTipo() {
         var dati = {nome : "recuperaCategorieAttributi", candidateFamiglie : $("#selectTipo").val()};
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "elaboraPhp.php",
               data: dati,
               error: function(data) {alert(data);},
               success: function(result) {
                    var arrayRitorno = eval (result);
                    $("#selectCategorie").empty();
                    for (var index in arrayRitorno)
                    {
                        if (index == 0) {
                            $("#selectCategorie").val(arrayRitorno[index]);
                        }
                        $("#selectCategorie").append($("<option value='"+arrayRitorno[index]+"'>"+arrayRitorno[index]+"</option>"));
                    }
                    RiempiDivConElementi();
               }
            });
```

in my page i have 2 select:

1_ Standard items create with html. When i change this a function has been called to fill the second select with the correct option.
2_When i select item on the second select i call a function that fill a div.

All working properly excluding the getting value of second select.

Anyone have solution for this problem??

EDIT:

This is my select in html:

```
<label for="selectCategorie">Categoria:</label>
    <select id="selectCategorie" name="selectCategorie">
        <!-- CARICATO AUTOMATICAMENTE NON APPENA SI SCEGLIE IL TIPO -->
    </select>
```

SOLUTION:

I find a solution:

In my opinion the problem is when i try to get value by #selector of jquery but in the DOM it doesn't exist because i generate it on client side without change DOM.

I change function like this:

```
function CaricaDaTipo() {
     var dati = {nome : "recuperaCategorieAttributi", candidateFamiglie : $("#selectTipo").val()};
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "elaboraPhp.php",
           data: dati,
           error: function(data) {alert(data);},
           success: function(result) {
                var arrayRitorno = eval (result);
                var catSel = "";
                $("#selectCategorie").empty();
                for (var index in arrayRitorno)
                {
                    if (index == 0) {
                        $("#selectCategorie").val(arrayRitorno[index]);
                        catSel = arrayRitorno[index];
                    }
                    $("#selectCategorie").append($("<option value='"+arrayRitorno[index]+"'>"+arrayRitorno[index]+"</option>"));
                }
                RiempiDivConElementi(catSel);
           }
        }); 
}

function RiempiDivConElementi(cat) {
    var dati = {nome : "generaTabellaPermessiUtenti", scheda : $("#selectTipo").val(), categoria : cat, id : <?php echo($datiUtenteCaricati['ID']);?> };
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "elaboraPhp.php",
           data: dati,
           error: function(data) {alert(data);},
           success: function(result) {
                $("#permessiAttributiDiv").html("");
                $("#permessiAttributiDiv").html(result);
           }
        }); 
}



$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#selectTipo").on("change", function(){
        CaricaDaTipo();
   });

   $("#selectCategorie").on("change", function(){
        RiempiDivConElementi($(this).val());
   });

   $("#permessiDiv input").on("change", "input", function(){

    )};

   CaricaDaTipo();


});
```

Now i pass variable with javascript without find it with jquery.
Now its all OK.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your select has `id="select"` ?

Comment: You should either use `$("select").val();` or `$("#selectCategorie").val();`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector to target select element.element have id `selectCategorie` and not `select`. `select` is tagname for dropdown. Thus you should use:

```
$("#selectCategorie").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken id='select' then your code is perfect. Other wise write

```
$("select").val();
```

Your edited questions answer -

```
$("#selectCategorie").val();
```